# Does DROP PROC automatically REVOKE EXEC on procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Quick question (I've looked in BOL but can't find an answer)...

If I run:

```
DROP PROC myProc
```

Does that automatically `REVOKE EXEC` to all users who previously had `GRANT EXEC` set?
It occurred to me this morning I've been dropping proc's for years but never thought to revoke access first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropping the procedure also drops all permissions associated with that procedure.

If you `CREATE PROC` again you will need to reassign the permissions.

Comment: Excellent - that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the timely response!